# window.open with target name not working in edge in IE mode

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, user-interface, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

We have a .NET application in which from UI in JS we are using window.open("","TabName").
On clicking the link which has to perform this window.open it is continuously opening the URL in new tabs instead of opening in same tab which it opened for the first time in Edge with IE mode.
The same works fine when used in Chrome or native edge. We are expecting that on using target name whichever tab opened on first click of the link should reopen everytime in that same tab on further clicks in edge in IE mode also same as chrome or native edge.

Comment: Do you store the reference returned from window.open?

Comment: in edge in IE mode its returning null, so storing it also doesn't help

Comment: I can not reproduce the problem.  window.open works as expected in Edge IE Mode.  It does not create multiple tabs and it also returns a reference that can be used to reload or close the tab.  So the problem seems specific to your environment, but the question doesn't include enough code or details to suggest a solution.

Comment: If the target site which you are opening using window.open to open a site which is not for edge in IE mode, then you will be able to replicate

Comment: Again, there is not enough information to reproduce the problem.  Calling window.open() displays the page with a banner that says "You are in Internet Explorer Mode".  And calling window.open() multiple times always opens in the same tab (not new tabs).  Please update the question with the actual code used and details about the environment where used.